# Spring data jpa's ManyToOne relationship: How to do a cascade update on a referenced primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Say I have a user table, the primary key is openId and it referenced as a foreign key of another tables:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Id
  String openId;
  String nickname;
  String city;
}
```

And another table references the user table:

```
@Entity
public class Gift {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  User user;
  String name;
  String image; 
  Long price;
}
```

Now acording the business change, I need to change the user's openId and I wonder is thera a way to update these existing referenced Gift records.

I did some try: if I firstly query a user and change its openId then I save the user like the following code:

```
User user = userRepo.findOne("o3sVZuA4p81wG24ph5Z5lmnrVhlc");
user.setOpenId("o3s");
userRepo.save(user);
```

and it won't update the user but insert a new user record to the user table.

So How can I update a existing user records and update the referenced gift record's user field cascadly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code same to edit and save your Object to the Database (No new Field will be added to your db Table).

```
 //initialize you EntityManager 
 // Transaction Begin
   obj_EntityManager.getTransaction().begin()
        //and Now here is the code to Update Your Rows.
    user = v_objEm.find(User.class, ID);
    user .setPassword(prm_Password);
     // set another Fields that belongs to your
    obj_EntityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    obj_EntityManager.close();
```

> Note :- This code is working with my `jpa` Configured Project to update a Record of User Table.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't *change* the ID of an entity**. The ID uniquely identifies an entity object. Different ID = different entity object. You can manually edit the value of the annotated `@Id` column in the database, sure; but for all purposes, that record is now a *different* entity object, because it has a different ID.
For any framework to *know* that your `User` is the same `User` despite having a different ID, there'd have to exist some other internal column that could be used to identify the User. Something like "oh, ok, the `openID` is different but the `socialSecurityNumber` is the same, so it's the same `User`". But then again, your ID would not be the `openID` field: you'd have to annotate `socialSecurityNumber` as the actual `@Id` so the framework knows.

And in fact, in your example you're doing this:

```
User user = userRepo.findOne("o3sVZuA4p81wG24ph5Z5lmnrVhlc");
```

So it seems like you *do* have a unique ID `"o3sVZuA4p81wG24ph5Z5lmnrVhlc"`, it's only that you haven't declared it in your `User`.

Just remove the `@Id` annotation from `openId` and declare that other field as `@Id`. That way you'd be able to update the `openID` of any `User` and have it reflected in every `Gift` too.